# does docker useable on windows platform?

Tags: java, linux, docker, ubuntu, centos

I'm new in linux and docker. do They have any relation to each other ?my means is how docker manage itself and how its container use the kernel. I'm a java developer and working on a microservice base project that's are run on linux servers.
and with witch logic, docker framework manages it's elements.

Comment: I'm not sure how your title fits with your question. But to answer the title, yes, docker is available on windows.

Comment: Docker is available on Windows. You need WSL2 to run Linux images though.

Answer (score 1):

Most docker images are linux based and if run on a linux host they share the necessary parts of the kernel.

Docker for Windows uses WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). With this linux container can be run on Windows.
Differences still occur with e.g. file paths.